# authorize on self record for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pundit

Using the pundit gem, authorization on the record id for a given user on the user model is proving to be a challenge

```
def initialize(user, record)
  @user = user
  @record = record
end


def image
  return true if record.user_id == user.id
end
```

generates a `undefined method 'user_id'` error.

Answer (score 0):

Silly...  Succinct answer.

```
def image
  record.id == user.id
end
```